# i need to pivot a table in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
select team,medal,COUNT(*) AS no_of_medals from athletes where medal != 'NA' GROUP BY team,medal order by team,medal
```

I need output in the following format

```
team gold silveR bronze
USA  3     4     6
```

Comment: share sample input and output

Comment: input
Denmark/Sweden Gold 1
Finland Bronze 5
Finland Gold 3
Netherlands Bronze 1
Netherlands Silver 1
Norway Bronze 2
Norway Gold 5
Norway Silver 3
output
team      gold    silver    bronze
USA        2         3          4

Answer (score 2):

Use [`TOTAL()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc) aggregate function for each type of medal:

```
SELECT team, 
       TOTAL(medal = 'Gold') gold,
       TOTAL(medal = 'Silver') silver,
       TOTAL(medal = 'Bronze') bronze
FROM athletes 
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY team;
```

Comment: thanks it worked as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
select team,medal,COUNT(*) AS no_of_medals from athletes where medal != 'NA' GROUP BY team,medal order by team,medal
)
pivot (sum(no_of_medals) for medal in ('gold', 'silveR', 'bronze'));
```

Comment: thanks for your response but in sqlite we cant use pivot function.